# Returning a list of a custom object with JPQL

Tags: json, hibernate, jpql

I am using Hibernate, and I'm trying to return some info about users which are saved in 2 separate tables.

The query I've made:

```
@Entity(name = "Users")
@Table(name = "Users")
@NamedQueries(
        { 
        @NamedQuery(name = QueryNames.QUERY_USER_GET_ALL_USERS_BASIC_INFO,
                    query = "select u.userId, p.personName, p.personMobile, p.personEmail, u.userStaus, u.usertype, p.personNotes "
                          + "FROM Person p JOIN User u ON p.personId = u.userPersonId "
                          + "Where u.Active = 1")
        })

public class User
{ ... }
```

I have made a class called `BasicUserInfo` to contain all the members I return in the select clause (just a class with members only and no method for Json purposes).

The way I'm trying to make it work is like this:

```
List<BasicUserInfo> list = list(namedQuery(QueryNames.QUERY_USER_GET_ALL_USERS_BASIC_INFO));
```

However, this does not compile since the last line with the activation above got an error:

> Type mismatch: cannot convert from `List<User>` to `List<UserBasicInfo>`

What can I do to make the query return the type of list I want? Or even just a list of `Object[]` is also good for Json purposes.

Comment: We have no idea what the list() and the namedQuery() methods do, and how they are declared.

Comment: It's a part of Dropwizard's API. It's running the query and converting the result to a List

Comment: Well, this method is declared to return a List<User>, although what your query is actually returning is a List<Object[]>. Just don't use that method. Use EntityManager's API (or Hibernat's Session API).

Comment: OK there might be a generic type passing somewhere. How do I create an EntityManager using Dropwizard and Jersey?

Comment: please share the code used for UserBasicInfo class.

Comment: I managed to solve this issue and posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I eventually did was changing the query to begin like this:

```
"select new com.myPackage.Users.UserBasicInfo(u.userId, p.personName, p.personMobile, p.personEmail, u.userStaus, u.usertype, p.personNotes) ...
```

The type needs to have a constructor which accepts the arguments returned by the query.